# Understanding Cisco Extended ACL

Tags: cisco, acl

I am trying to limit access to our SIP servers to only `209.85.2.10` however,
I am getting a little confused by the `permit ip any any log`. Will it not allow everything in? Without it, I loose all the rest of the needed traffic.

Question, how do I limit access to `5060` to only `permit ip any any log` and retain the rest of the traffic (ie, http, smtp..).

The `permit ip any any log` seems to contradict the constraint by allowing other servers to connect.

Internal Network

```
 interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip access-group 104 out
 exit

 ip access-list extended 104
 permit udp host 209.85.2.10 host 192.168.2.5 eq 5060 log
 permit ip any any log
 deny ip any any log
 deny tcp any any log
 deny udp any any log
 exit
```

**Update**

So I need to change the above to

```
 ip access-list extended 104
 permit udp host 209.85.2.10 host 192.168.2.5 eq 5060 log
 deny ip any host 192.168.2.5 log
 permit ip any any log
 exit
```

Then this will work as expected?

i) Accept `5060` access to `192.168.2.5` only from `209.85.2.10`, and deny the rest of the attempts on the `5060` port
ii) Let other traffic in from anywhere to anywhere within the network but `5060`?

**Update Final Product**

For those who will find this post in the future. Here is the config that works for me thanks to the help of the two gentlemen in this thread.

```
ip access-list extended 104
permit tcp any host 192.168.2.5 eq 53
permit udp any host 192.168.2.5 eq 53
permit tcp any host 192.168.2.10 eq 25
permit tcp any host 192.168.2.10 eq 587
permit tcp any host 192.168.2.10 eq 993
permit tcp any host 192.168.2.10 eq 995
permit tcp any host 192.168.2.15 eq 80
permit tcp any host 192.168.2.15 eq 443
permit udp host 205.205.22.186 host 192.168.2.5 eq 5060
permit udp host 205.205.74.186 host 192.168.2.5 eq 5060
permit udp host 70.83.45.11 host 192.168.2.5 eq 5060
permit udp any host 192.168.2.20 eq 5080
permit udp any host 192.168.2.5 range 8000 65535
permit tcp any eq 25 host 192.168.2.10 range 1024 65535 established
permit tcp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.5 range 1024 65535 established
permit tcp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.10 range 1024 65535 established
permit tcp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.15 range 1024 65535 established
permit tcp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.20 range 1024 65535 established
permit udp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.5 range 1024 65535
permit udp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.10 range 1024 65535
permit udp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.15 range 1024 65535
permit udp any eq 53 host 192.168.2.20 range 1024 65535
permit tcp any eq 80 host 192.168.2.5 range 1024 65535 established
permit tcp any eq 80 host 192.168.2.10 range 1024 65535 established
permit tcp any eq 80 host 192.168.2.15 range 1024 65535 established
permit tcp any eq 80 host 192.168.2.20 range 1024 65535 established
deny ip any host 192.168.2.5 log
deny ip any host 192.168.2.10 log
deny ip any host 192.168.2.15 log
deny ip any host 192.168.2.20 log
permit ip any any
exit

ip nat inside source static 192.168.2.5 77.77.77.77 route-map voip-rtp extendable
```

Thanks in Advance,

Nick.

Comment: You really, really want to get rid of the `log` on the `permit ip any any log` statement. This will kill your router's performance and probably drive it's CPU utilization to unacceptable levels. Typically, you only want to log specific `deny` statements, if at all.

Comment: Hello Ron, the log messages are just for testing. I want to see the how the network packets get shaped and play nicely with the router. Once this is done, I will remove the `log` from accepts. One example is:
`: %SEC-6-IPACCESSLOGP: list 104 permitted udp 105.105.211.10(11180) -> 192.168.2.5(23854), 9746 packets`
This accept is a big deal for me. It's a port range accept on the udp. A hot topic these days.... ;)

Comment: As long as you understand that you may lose packets due to high CPU utilization on the router. I know someone who put log on everything, and he couldn't figure out why the performance was so bad. He was leaving the logging on to try to figure it out, but the logging itself was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hahaha how elusive! I am just logging for debugging purposes. Once it's all figured out and traffic is flowing nicely both ways, i'll drop the logs. The logs were how I learned the ins and outs of ACL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***first*** of all
there is no host called 209.85.2.0 this is sort of network , you must configure it as a network not as a host

***permit udp 209.85.2.0 0.0.0.255 host 192.168.2.5 eq 5060 log***

***second***
you don't need
*deny ip any any log*
*deny tcp any any log*
*deny udp any any log*
cause the access list has its own explicate deny so in your case you just need to permit the type of access you want

***third***
 you need to know that access list working by the concept of the first match 
where for example as you configured your access list that is mean ,When any one in 209.85.2.0 need to access host 192.168.2.5 ,this access list will allow only UDP access on port 5060 by its first line.

Then you have other 3 cases that won't match this line and will go to next ACL lines
 1. Any network other than  209.85.2.0 need to access 192.168.2.5
 2. Any one in network  209.85.2.0 need to access anything other than 192.168.2.5
 3. Any one need to access any other network

your ACL second line means you will permit any one to access anything *even  192.168.2.5 on port 5060*.**which is wrong** . if you need to prevent any other network from access this host you just need to insert those 3 lines after your first line

***deny ip any host  192.168.2.5 log***

and then insert
***permit ip any any log*** which will allow access to other servers from any where

Comment: Thanks Gadlow. `host 209.85.2.01` was a bad example. I just wanted to change the server ip for security reasons. Please see update

Comment: `permit ip any any log which will allow access to other servers from any where`, that is for services other than 5060 correct?

Comment: permit ip any any log will allow any thing to access any thing even 5060 , but for other hosts other than 192.168.2.5

Comment: Checking this and will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: You don't need these two lines (in your second example): deny tcp any host 192.168.2.5 log deny udp any host 192.168.2.5 log The line above deny ip any host 192.168.2.5 log will block TCP and UDP traffic (As well as ICMP) One other point: You may want to reconsider putting the "log" keywords on your permit statements. That causes the CPU be interrupted by each packet to process all the logging. Depending on the amount of traffic, it can put a heavy load on the router.